# C++: Unable to pass vector to the constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

So I am very new at C++ and I have been given a task of creating a class along with its header file so test.h and test.cpp.
Now I need to create a constructor that takes a vector of doubles as an argument and uses it to initialise
the object. However, I am not able to figure out how to accurately do this. This is what I have added on my header and cpp class and I'm getting an error

Header file:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Dog
{
    int age;
    string name;
    vector<long double> myVector;
public:

    Dog();   
    Dog(string name, int age, vector<long double> myVector);
};
#endif // DOG_H
```

cpp file:

```
using namespace std;
Dog::Dog()
{
   cout << "Dog object created"<< endl;   
}

Dog::Dog(string name, int age, vector<long double> myVector)
: name(name), age(age), myVector(myVector.push_back(myVector))
{
    cout << name<<" "<< age <<" "<<myVector<< endl;
}
```

now in my main class if i add this:

```
Dog d("Kelly",3,988);
```

and run the program I get the no match for operator error.

Comment: `988` is not a vector.  Do you want a vector that has a single element of `988` or a vector of size `988`?

Comment: Also having the same name for vector member and for constructor parameter doesn't sound like a good idea for me. This: `myVector(myVector.push_back(myVector))` surely will be a problem...

Comment: The constructor needs a vector<long double> so you need to pass one when calling it. 988 is no vector<long double> and there is no implicit conversion to it.

Comment: @alseether having same name for constructor parameter and member is not a problem per se, though `myVector(myVector.push_back(myVector))` is certainly not correct

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 true. I would replace *idea* for *practice* on my previous sentence

Comment: @alseether matter of opinion, most of my contructor parameters are not used anywhere but in the initializer list and then I find it wasteful to use a different name for it when there is no need

Comment: This is where you add `this->` to make things work as expected :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the third parameter as a vector, or as something that can be used in the constructor of a vector.

If you want a vector with one element of 988 then use:

```
Dog d("Kelly", 3, { 988 });
```

This uses an [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which a vector can be [constructed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) from.

This will highlight another problem, that the `myVector` member variable is not correctly initialised in the initializer list. Instead this should look something like:

```
Dog::Dog(string name, int age, vector<long double> v) : name(name), age(age), myVector(v)
```

This copies the elements in the parameter `v` into `myVector`.

It is also recommended not to have a `using namespace std` in header files. This is because anyone who `#include <Dog.h>` will end up with the `std` namespace at the top level. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/1517648

Comment: Still getting an error with Dog d("Kelly", 3, { 988 });.. It says error: converting to 'std::vector<long double>' from initializer list...

Comment: What compiler are you using?